# Handle jqGrid change event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and I want to trigger a custom event when jqGrid changes. By jqGrid change I mean add/remove a row, after editing a cell value so I have done this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#_jqGrid').on('change', function () {
        $.event.trigger('myCustomEvent');
    });
});
```

Is it right to handle jqGrid change event or is there another way to do this, for example, handle another more correct jqGrid event?

Comment: No i dont think jQGrid got `onchange` implementation. check out the documentation for handling different events like beforeCellSubmit, etc

Comment: `change` event is wrong in case of editing the grid. To answer on your question it's important to know **which one [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you use**.

Comment: Is it possible to subscribe to a jqgrid event when its content (in my case it is binding to a model) changes?